# Detecting changes to an input value - vue2

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using a [date time picker component](https://github.com/mengxiong10/vue2-datepicker) for vue2. While it renders nicely and seem to function well with basic usage, I am not able to detect changes to the input value within the vue component. I tried adding `@change` to the component instance, although it never seems to fire. Any idea why this is? Note, v-model updates the value of `cool` successfully.

Vue Methods

```
 export default {
        ...           
        methods: {
          someEvent() {
            alert("SUCCESS"); //this never fires
          }
```

Vue Markup

```
                       <date-picker
                                v-model="cool"
                                lang="en"
                                type="datetime"
                                input-class="date-time-picker"
                                format="MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A"
                                @change="someEvent()"
                                :confirm="true"
                        >
                        </date-picker>
```

JsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/aw5g3q9x/

Answer (score 5):

When you add an event listener to a component tag (such as `@change="someEvent()"`), Vue will listen for a *custom* event to be emitted from the component. The `<date-picker>` component never emits a custom `change` event. [Looking at the documentation](https://github.com/mengxiong10/vue2-datepicker), it appears that it only ever emits a `confirm` event when the optional "OK" button is pressed.

Your best option is to set a watcher on the `cool` property to fire the `someEvent` method whenever the value of `cool` changes:

```
watch: {
  cool() {
    this.someEvent();
  }
}
```

---

For future reference, if the root element of the component was an `input`, you could use the `.native` modifier to listen for the change DOM event of that `input` element like so `@change.native="someEvent()"`. However, the root element of the `<date-picker>` component is a `div`, so that wouldn't work in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know the datepicker, but in your case you can use variable change watcher

```js
Vue.use(window.DatePicker.default)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
   return {
     value: ''
    }
  },
  watch: {
      value() {
        alert("OK");
      }
 }
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//rawgit.com/mengxiong10/vue2-datepicker/master/dist/build.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <date-picker v-model="value" lang="en" type="datetime" format="yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a" :time-picker-options="{
                                     start: '00:00',
                                     step: '00:30',
                                     end: '23:30'
                                     }"></date-picker>
                                     
                                     {{ value }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have seen the package you are using for date time picker and I doubt they support `@change` event. Are you sure they do?

As a work around however, You can use computed properties or watchers to watch for changes in the `value` variable. Here is the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/aw5g3q9x/2/